# How to install this NuGet package if i don't see it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, libraries

I want to download this https://github.com/BobLd/youtube-transcript-api-sharp, but i really can't, it's have a strange README, can anyone help?

I tried commands from README and finding this NugetPackage

UPD: Here's info what to do if u have git rep of library u need but it didn't publish to nuget store, thanks to Bowman Zhu-MSFT

Comment: If you use the nuget command line and insert the command on that readme what happens?

Comment: nothig? try it yourself

Comment: I think it has never been published to NuGet. And the command line in README.md is there from template. So you should probably get the project and build it youself.

Comment: If you check where its ported from you see exactly the same text but pip has been renamed to nuget. So @MikeMozhaev is correct, its never been published and the readme is unfinished.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev omg seems hard. So i need to clone this rep, and then? How can I build it myself?

Comment: @LeoSolo, you can either open the solution in Visual Studio, build it and get the required dll(s), or add the project to your solution and then add project reference to that project in your project.

Comment: Copy the the directory `YoutubeTranscriptApi` next to your project directory where you want to use it. Then add the csproj to your solution via right click > add > existing project.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev what has this profession come to when even copy & pasting source code is considered "hard" 

Comment: Hi Leo, I posted a detailed step by step answer(From getting source code to use it in another project.). I tried to avoid using command or other knowledge points that require extended learning. You can follow the answer I gave step by step. Please note that this answer is just for you to get started quickly, so I have simplified some steps in it. You can use it to expand some knowledge points that you didn't know before if you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may not have a good understanding of some features in Visual Studio and the concepts related to Nuget packages. Below I will provide a specific step as simple as possible based on the source code you provided.

> How to install this NuGet package if I don't see it?

I think what you said can't be seen means that you can't find it in the [nuget gallery](https://www.nuget.org/), right?

[image]

The Nuget Gallery is the nuget source of the default configuration of the nuget management of VS Tools (if you just download a VS and start, then this is the source), and it is also the central package repository of the NuGet package manager officially maintained by Microsoft.

But nuget package repository doesn't only have one choice in VS Tools. VS Tools not only supports Microsoft's official package repository, you can use third-party package repository or even local package repository(local folders).

The following contents will tell you how to generate a package based on the source code to local repository and make it visable in VS Tools as usual.

---

**1, Git clone the repository.**

`git clone https://github.com/BobLd/youtube-transcript-api-sharp.git`

If you didn't do this step before or don't have experience on this, you need first download Git via this: [Git download](https://git-scm.com/downloads). And then find out where is the git command exe, configure it to Path of system environment variables(This step will make you be able to use the git command in any where in your system.).

[image]

[image]

**2, Install the VS Tools(I installed VS2022 community 17.4.4), and prepare .net 5 when install.**

The code you provided is based on .net 5:

[image]

This is why you need to prepare .net 5.

If you doesn't install before, you can follow below steps to install .net 5:

Search and click in Visual Studio Installer:

[image]

Modify the VS Tool you want to update:

[image]

[image]

**3, Prepare the package.**

Go to the root directory of the cloned source code repository:

[image]

Right click project 'YoutubeTranscriptApi' in Solution Explorer of VS Tool, and click 'Set as Startup Project':

[image]

Change the build configuration of 'YoutubeTranscriptApi' to Release:

[image]

Right Click project 'YoutubeTranscriptApi' and click Properties:

[image]

Select check box 'Produce a package file during build operations' in Package -> General:

[image]

Right Your project 'YoutubeTranscriptApi' and click 'Rebuild':

[image]

Then the package will be generated with the default package configurations to local path:

[image]

You can configure the above local path as the package source in VS Tool:

[image]

[image]

[image]

the path I configured is:

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reproduce\cloned_app\youtube-transcript-api-sharp\YoutubeTranscriptApi\bin\Release`

You just need to make sure this path have the package you want.

You can see the package after change package source in Package management:

[image]

---

**Finally, I can use the package with no problem:**

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using YoutubeTranscriptApi;

namespace UsePackage
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var videoId = "xxx";
            using (var youTubeTranscriptApi = new YouTubeTranscriptApi())
            {
                var transcriptItems = youTubeTranscriptApi.GetTranscript(videoId);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: omg this really works thanks man you're awesome, but my project is on .NET framework 4.8 and now i thinks how to migrate on .NET 5 or maybe add this as sedond project in the solution and link it, idk, Thanks a lot, love u