# Can't install nuget package in VS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

When I am going to install a nuget package in Visual Studio Pro 2022 (17.5.4), it shows the following error:

> Error NU1102
> Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms with version (>= 5.0.0)
> Found 5 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 3.1.0 ]
>
> - Found 0 version(s) in Package source
> - Found 0 version(s) in MyCollectData.Library.0.0.12

Comment: try `dotnet restore` and `nuget.exe restore` from the CLI

Comment: @styx doesn't resolve

Comment: Clear the nuget cache and try to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the package manager console or the Nuget package manager UI?

If you were based on the previous one, you can use this command to check the source of Nuget:

`nuget sources`

If you were based on the second one, check the the source of Nuget package here:

[image]

The above steps are checking whether these is available package source to download.

Of course, you can also download the package directly here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/8.0.0-preview.3.23174.8

[image]

And then follow this to configure the local folder as package source:

[How to install this NuGet package if i don't see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462220/how-to-install-this-nuget-package-if-i-dont-see-it/75469556#75469556)