# Unable to load the service index from source

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I want to download a System.Data.SqlClient in Visual Studio and then I download it from Manage NuGet Packages for Solution (right-click on the Solution Explorer). When I try to browse that, it looks very slow and I found another way to install the packages from the NuGet website using Package Manager Console by running this command,

```
NuGet\Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.8.5
```

but it looks very slow too. Is it another way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Edit:
Try to access the URL (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) it can't open, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You can check my answer, another method to achieve your requirement. :)

Comment: Hi Bim, any update of this issue? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering may just be a temporary network fluctuation, or it may be that VS is too slow.

The method you are currently using is indeed a viable method.

In addition, I can recommend you another method, that is to the official library (Nuget Gallery):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient

Then download directly:

[image]

After that, you can follow this answer to configure the local folder as package source:

[How to install this NuGet package if i don't see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462220/how-to-install-this-nuget-package-if-i-dont-see-it/75469556#75469556)

Comment: Hello, @Bowman sorry for the late reply because I was on holiday yesterday. Basically, it was my fault when I started the project by choosing "Windows Forms App" not "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)". I already try your suggestion to directly downloaded from the website but still does not work. But when I Choose "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" the problem is clear and the problem is based on what you said.